# Grouping Arrays By Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash

I have the following array that I'd like to transform into an Object with unique `hobbies` as the keys

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Joe', hobbies: ['skating', 'biking', 'music'] },
  { name: 'Kim', hobbies: ['fishing', 'biking', 'karate'] },
  { name: 'Ben', hobbies: ['surfing'] },
]
```

I use lodash's handy `groupBy` function but it groups the multiple array elements into single keys like so

```
{
  'skating,biking,music': [
    { name: 'Joe' }
  ],
  'fishing,biking,karate': [
    { name: 'Kim' }
  ],
  'surfing': [
    { name: 'Ben' }
  ],
}
```

What I need is the following output (note the objects are repeated for each of their respective hobbies)

```
{
  biking: [
    { name: 'Joe' },
    { name: 'Kim' }
  ],
  skating: [
    { name: 'Joe' }
  ],
  karate: [
    { name: 'Kim' }
  ],
  surfing: [
    { name: 'Ben' }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Is there a simple way to group this array without looping through each array element, splitting them up and regrouping? Would like to avoid this if there's better utility method out there I'm unaware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate each item and each hobbie and then add it to a `result` object:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Joe', hobbies: ['skating', 'biking', 'music'] },
  { name: 'Kim', hobbies: ['fishing', 'biking', 'karate'] },
  { name: 'Ben', hobbies: ['surfing'] }
]

const result = {};
arr.forEach(item => 
  item.hobbies.forEach(hobbie => 
    result[hobbie] = (result[hobbie] || []).concat({name: item.name})
  )
)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works just how I need it to

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'Joe', hobbies: ['skating', 'biking', 'music'] },
  { name: 'Kim', hobbies: ['fishing', 'biking', 'karate'] },
  { name: 'Ben', hobbies: ['surfing'] }
]

const result = {};
arr.forEach(item => 
  item.hobbies.forEach(hobbie => 
    result[hobbie] = result[hobbie]?[...result[hobbie],{name: item.name}]: [{name: item.name}]
  )
)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed `arr` to `people` for better understanding.

```js
const people = [
  { name: 'Joe', hobbies: ['skating', 'biking', 'music'] },
  { name: 'Kim', hobbies: ['fishing', 'biking', 'karate'] },
  { name: 'Ben', hobbies: ['surfing'] },
];

function transform(people) {
  // get all hobbies and remove duplicates
  const hobbies = [... new Set(
    people.reduce((hobbies, person) => hobbies.concat(person.hobbies),  [])
  )];
  const res = {};
  // take a hobby and use it as key
  for (let hobby of hobbies) {
    res[hobby] = people
      .filter((person) => person.hobbies.includes(hobby))
      .map((person) => { return { name: person.name }; });
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(transform(people));
```